# What kind of precision can the Tango achieve?

Tags: precision, google-project-tango

I'm looking to develop a high precision scanning app and can't seem to find the specs on the precision of the point-cloud.
Does anyone know or has anyone tested the precision of individual points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my experience with Tango device, on an average you can achieve 10fps temporal resolution with Depth Camera. Pointcloud density depends on lot of factors

- **Lighting conditions in room**, as structured light based sensors throw IR pattern on scene, presence of Sunlight will affect depth camera badly
- **Reflective surfaces/Glasses**, IR pattern of structured light gets reflected from glasses and at times go through glass surfaces, distorting DepthMap
- **Distance from camera** Optimal operational range of tango depth camera is **0.5m-4m**, so it's better to have object to be scanned at **~1m** distance.

In my experience, when Tango device is at optimal distance from surfaces you get 15K points, in other cases around 6K points. More the points better the scan density.

Motion tracking functionality of Tango device use SLAM algorithm, presence of strong features in scene will help SLAM, help in obtaining precise motion tracking.

It's advised to use standard registration algorithms when you are scanning structures from different poses.